# git submodule update vs git submodule sync

Tags: git, git-submodules

The `git` documentation doesn't make it at all clear what the difference is between a `git submodule update` and a `git submodule sync` is. I'm also not finding any help out on the web. Can someone help me out with what the difference is here?

```
   update
       Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject expects
       by cloning missing submodules and updating the working tree of the
       submodules. The "updating" can be done in several ways depending on
       command line options and the value of submodule.<name>.update
       configuration variable.
```

-

```
   sync
       Synchronizes submodules' remote URL configuration setting to the value
       specified in .gitmodules. It will only affect those submodules which
       already have a URL entry in .git/config (that is the case when they are
       initialized or freshly added). This is useful when submodule URLs
       change upstream and you need to update your local repositories
       accordingly.
```

For reference, I'm using the git client version 2.11.0

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`update` is basically doing `git pull` in each submodule (except without a branch, since the main repo specifies a commit directly).

The tricky one is `sync`. Imagine you clone a project with submodules, then later the upstream project *changes* one of the submodules to point to a different URL.

Your local copy of the submodule will still point to the old URL, since git *never* allows remote repositories to force a change to local configuration. You need to run `git submodule sync` to apply the remote repo's configuration to your local submodule repos.

Note also that, if you are making *changes* to the submodules, you might *want* the URLs to mismatch even if the upstream never changed them ... but using *multiple* remote URLs is probably a better idea for that case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your URL mismatch comment. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You might not have *permission* to push directly to the repo that's being used as a submodule. So you push to your fork, then make a PR to the main submodule repo.

Comment: A note for those searching on how to push: If you do have permission to push to the remote repository, you don't use a git submodule command, but can enter the submodule directory and use a normal git commands from there.

Answer (score 68):

`git submodule update` updates the *contents* of the submodules. It is effectively running a "git fetch" and "git checkout" in each of your submodules.

`git submodule sync` updates the *metadata* about a submodule to reflect changes in the submodule URL.  It re-synchronizes the information in `.git/config` with the information in `.gitmodules`.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. Does `git submodule init` imply a `git submodule sync` as well? I've been using a remote repo with multiple submodules and doing `git submodule init; git submodule update` after a `git pull` and have never gotten out of sync.

Comment: I don't know, but it seems like that would be a relatively easy test.

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber Off topic, but maybe use `&&` instead of `;` to separate your commands. This way, the following command will not execute if the first one failed.

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber, You only need to do a ```git submodule update``` everytime you do a ```git pull``` on your main repository, unless you're setting up the git submodule for the first time on a newly cloned main repo.